# Working with a Java Mail Server for Testing

Tags: java, testing, email, mail-server

I'm in the process of testing an application that takes mail out of a mailbox, performs some action based on the content of that mail, and then sends a response mail depending on the result of the action.

I'm looking for a way to write tests for this application.  Ideally, I'd like for these tests to bring up their own mail server, push my test emails to a folder on this mail server, and have my application scrape the mail out of the mail server that my test started.

Configuring the application to use the mailserver is not difficult, but I do not know where to look for a programatic way of starting a mail server in Java.  I've looked at JAMES, but I am unable to figure out how to start the server from within my test.

So the question is this: What can I use for a mail server in Java that I can configure and start entirely within Java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is also very simple in use [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/) which was designer as a mail server for automatic "unit" tests.

From projects web page (probably there are some others tools with sending/receiving functionality nowadays):

> GreenMail is an open source, intuitive
>   and easy-to-use test suite of email
>   servers for testing purposes. Supports
>   SMTP, POP3, IMAP with SSL socket
>   support. GreenMail also provides a
>   JBoss GreenMail Service. GreenMail is
>   the fist and only library that offers
>   a test framework for both receiving
>   and retrieving emails from Java.

Comment: I had problems with Greenmail mysteriously duplicating the 'TO' and 'CC' recipients into the 'TO' list of the envelope, casuing my tests to fail. This happened when I was sending an email to two 'TO' and one 'CC' recipients. I then switched to SubEthaSmtp/Wiser, and things worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I've used both [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/) and [SubEthaSmtp](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp) in unit tests before to test code that sends email.

I found Dumbster to be far easier to work with.

Comment: Charlie wants to test email fetching, Dumbster and SubEthaSmtp are for sending mail.

Comment: Both are email servers capable of receiving email as well.

Comment: Just integrated SubEthaSmtp (Particularly the Wiser SMTP server), and it seemed quite straight-forward. It can handle attachements, and inlined images e.t.c. very well.

Comment: You can't work with the mail body in dumbster. Dumbster is [broken](http://sourceforge.net/p/dumbster/bugs/15/).

Comment: It seems Dumbster is not so much stable. SubethaSMTP team reimplements it on the `Wiser` project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JES](http://www.ericdaugherty.com/java/mailserver/), seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Dumbster: Fast to setup! But can't handle mail attachments. There only strings at the end of the body and have to be parsed separately.

So now I'm trying another framework

Answer (score 0):

#### The [Mock-JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/mock-javamail) project

I came across it when developing a plugin for Jenkins, and it's been a dream to use!

Just [drop the dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jvnet.mock-javamail%7Cmock-javamail%7C1.9%7Cjar) into your project, and you're ready to go (I'll let [Kohsuke explain](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/introducing_moc.html) how to set it up and use it).

If you're impatient, here's a quick example of how it's used:

#### Example:

```
// Setup test: add mail to inbox
Mailbox tmp = Mailbox.get("foo@bar.com");
tmp.add(/* your javax.mail.Message */)
assertEquals 1, tmp.size()

// Connect to the inmemory mailbox using "imap"
Session session = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
Store store = session.getStore('imap');
store.connect("bar.com","foo","anything");

// Check the mail exists!
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
assertEquals 1, inbox.getMessageCount()
store.close();
```