# How to load dummy/fake/mock emails and email folders to a shared IMAP account to test MUA configs?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, imap, email

**Summary**

How do I create a set of on-demand, mock/dummy/fake emails in numerous
IMAP folders? Email content needs to be share-able in a public forum via
a commonly-access IMAP-server account (typically for testers/developers
trying to debug [MUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) problems/configurations), with no privacy
risks.

I haven't yet found a solution to do this. Unless I can find something
(I'm totally looking for suggestions), I'm relegated to writing my own
software client. If so, I'd do it in Python, and I'm looking for general
pointers on which tools/libraries/methods/approaches I should employ to
most-quickly get a first, working prototype.

How should I solve the above, given the context below?

**Purpose**

I want to test various [MUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) deployments, sharing the same IMAP
account between many users/testers/developers (of any MUA) in a
public arena. Example: I might ask on a Notmuch email list:

"Why is my [mbsync/Notmuch](https://github.com/johnnyutahh/search-based-email)
config not working? Here's a shared gmail.com account we can
collectively use as a common IMAP server to minimize server-side
variables and thus collectively help debug stuff."

**IMAP-Client Requirements**

The IMAP-client program:

- must be able to create a variable number of nested IMAP folders with any
  number emails,
- must prove all email content and folder names are share-able,
  with no privacy concerns (any reasonable content will do,
  and it doesn't have to make sense; eg #1: variants of [Lorem
  ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) might work; eg #1:
  provide input for 3 or more example emails, provided by the user/caller)
  so long as the emails can be opened and read by MUAs, and their
  attachments are "real" enough to be opened by the attachment-file's
  corresponding application,
- will include some number of emails with 1 or more attachments,
- will optimally (but not required for initial versions) be capable
  of generating GB's of content by creating many thousands of emails in
  hundreds of nested IMAP folders. The client can leverage many or large
  file attachments will help do this.
- must be able to do all of the above on-demand, given any new/fresh
  IMAP-server account credentials.

As an implementation shortcut, it's ok for the client to duplicate
much/most of the email conent, so long as there's significant variance
in Date:, To:, From:, and Subject: headers and email-folder names (all
of which are presumably easy to "randomize").

**More Details**

I've pondered trying to non-private-ize existing emails/folders from
IMAP accounts I already have (that serve the above requirements), but
that work appears way too hard. Too much personal, sensitive information
would need to be "converted"/"private-ized." However, I'd like to hear
options for ways to easily privatize (scramble, encrypt, something?)
this existing email content. Such a path might save me having to write
the software.

The only way I see to solve this properly: leverage an IMAP client
program (again, I'm presumably writing it) that can create emails and
email folders on any designated IMAP server/account. Program input can
include example (presumably private) email content, number of folders
and nesting levels, randomness, date ranges (of emails), etc.

I've not yet found anything that does this.
[GreenMail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180322/605356) appears to setup
the IMAP server, but not the IMAP server content--unless I'm overlooking
something?

Comment: Logging to an IMAP server and managing folders should be easy with imaplib model of Python standard library. Generating messages with or without attachements can be done with the email module. In order to encrypt mail in a standard way, you may have a look to the M2Crypto module on pypi, but I have never tested that part. For the remaining, I'm afraid you question is way too broad...

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks. Do you know of any existing application (sans coding) which provides some or all of this functionality today?

Comment: Instead of generating the emails, I would look at using the archives of public mailing lists and/or the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus. This is a more realistic test of the system anyway.

Comment: That seems like a excellent idea, thanks @Jani.

Comment: Last time I looked, the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_Corpus email set had insufficient email headers for IMAP-server content. Similar idea with another dataset is great... and/or I auto-generate/supplement sufficient header content.